# Cannot resolve method when using consumer

Tags: java

I have an InputStream that load properties file. Normally I use `properties.load(is);` But I would like to change it to Consumer as I would like to avoid using catches so I created an ThrowingConsumer that's avoid id, but the problem is that even I use normal Consumer it seems to be working when I declare that will be an InputStream, but my ThrowingConsumer is generic so it looks like that

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Throwable>
{
    void accept(T t) throws E;

    static <T, E extends Throwable> Consumer<T> unchecked(ThrowingConsumer<T, E> consumer)
    {
        return t ->
        {
            try
            {
                consumer.accept(t);
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And when I use `ThrowingConsumer.unchecked(properties::load).accept(is);` it's screaming that cannot resolve method load. How could I avoid it?

Comment: There are several load methods. So use a lambda, or cast your method reference to ThrowingConsumer<InputStream, IOException>

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @JBNizet Could you give a code example with the issue above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The load() method is overloaded, so inference can't choose between the two overloads.

Use a lambda:

```
ThrowingConsumer.unchecked((InputStream i) -> properties.load(i)).accept(is);
```

or cast your method reference to the right type:

```
ThrowingConsumer.unchecked((ThrowingConsumer<InputStream, IOException>) properties::load).accept(is);
```

Quite frankly, I think you're abusing consumers here, and that a good old try catch block would make things much easier to read. UnsupportedOperationException is also not at all the correct exception to load when you can't read from an InputStream. UncheckedIOException would be much cleaner. And your consumer also catches exceptions that it shouldn't catch (such as NullPointerException, or OutOfMemoryError, etc.), without even chaining the original cause, making it very very hard to diagnose the problem at runtime.